# Cannot export raster with qgis2web or qgis2leaf

Tags: qgis2web, qgis2leaf

I am trying to publish a raster layer with qgis2web, when I set the parameters in the popup qgis2web window, the raster doesn´t show up in the preview window (there is a question mark instead). Then, after exporting/publishing, the folder with index.html file and other folders are created, but there is nothing inside the data folder, and the raster does not show on the index.html page.
A similar thing happens if trying with qgis2leaf.
Any idea of what might been wrong?
The raster is a 3 band composite RGB from Sentinel2 bands, saved as rendered raster, projection EPSG:4326.QGIS Version is 2.18.
Raster link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/l1dvxzq37oe10yp/7%20rendered.tif?dl=0

Comment: Confirmed that it fails with OpenLayers 3 export. However, it works for me with Leaflet export - can you confirm? I'll investigate the OpenLayers issue.

Comment: No, it doesn´t work with Leaflet export for me. Qgis MacOS ver 2.18.

Comment: Ah, perhaps you have the same bug as https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/issues/148#issuecomment-250157682. Some MacOS rasters fail. No fix for it yet, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there was a regression in qgis2web for OpenLayers 3 raster layers. I've committed a fix to the Github master branch at https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web. Please try that and leave a comment to this answer to say whether it fixes the problem or not.

Comment: thank you very much Tom,  but by knowledge is limited for executing your recommendation, I see the utils.py file that you have added, but I wouldn´t know how to proceed to try it. I´d be thankful if you adviced me  how.

Comment: On the page I linked to, click the green button "Clone or download", and choose "Download ZIP". Open the downloaded zip file, and copy the contents of the folder "qgis2web-master" over the contents of the qgis2web installation folder (the installation folder is listed in the plugin's details screen in the QGIS plugin manager). Then restart QGIS - you now have the most up-do-date development version of qgis2web. Try your raster again, and report back what happens.

Comment: I updated the folder content, but everything stays the same: there is no problem with vector layers, but with rasters, nothing show in preview when selecting OpenLayers 3, and I can see a square outline with a question mark in the center when selecting Leaflet.

Comment: Now, what I did is installed QGis Windows version on the same machine, with Parallels Desktop. Now, OpenLayers 3 doesn´t work but Leaflet does the export fine.

Comment: Can you post any errors, either from the QGIS Python console, or from the browser console?

Comment: sure, here it is:

Comment: Python Console 
Use iface to access QGIS API interface or Type help(iface) for more info
Unable to execute algorithm
Wrong parameter value: /var/folders/d8/m9jrqdx51ld16gtdw73mjz9w0000gn/T/SALVADOR407ENE2017VIS01487288357_piped_3857.tif
Unable to execute algorithm
Wrong parameter value: /var/folders/d8/m9jrqdx51ld16gtdw73mjz9w0000gn/T/SALVADOR407ENE2017VIS01487288362_piped_3857.tif
Unable to execute algorithm
Wrong parameter value: /var/folders/d8/m9jrqdx51ld16gtdw73mjz9w0000gn/T/SALVADOR407ENE2017VIS01487288365_piped_3857.tif

Comment: I think this is the same issue as the one I linked to in my comment to he question. I don't have a solution yet. Sorry.

Comment: Hi, any update on this? Solution on how to publish raster/s to web using qgis2web plugin?

Comment: Actually, yes. Can you upgrade to the latest version of qgis2web? I added a fix for rasters in the last week. Let us know if it works.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I checked and noticed that the installed version of qgis2web plugin is 2.17.1 from May 11th, but it still doesn't publish rasters. When selecting OL, I see a blank preview, and when selecting Leaflet I see a blank outline of the raster with a question mark in the center.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/nnjj09n37cs3vu2/LL.png?dl=0

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fr2vmsdfcvdylkp/OL.png?dl=0

Comment: OK, since this looks like there's still a problem, can we move the discussion over to https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/issues/148? If you can upload your raster and also the contents of the qgis2web log there, that would be great.